# Published Google Docs spreadsheet: one data set with 3 sheets each sorted differently

Tags: google-sheets

Is it possible on a published Google Docs spreadsheet to have 3 individual sheets, each sorted differently from the common data, and only update the common data?

Comment: Can you share a google spreadsheet with us?

Answer (score 1):

Let the raw data be in the first sheet. Then, use the QUERY function to populate the second and the third sheet.
Or, if you need more control, create another sheet for the raw data, and use the QUERY function to populate the first sheet also.

Comment: This led me in the right direction. End result is:  =sort('Ship Manifest Index'!A3:Q1057,4,true)